# Can we achieve response streaming using an AWS ALB or NLB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, streaming, load-balancing, responsestream

We are building a flask application wherein for a specific request we want to be able to stream the response to the client.
Something like this

```
@app.route("/time/")
def time():
    def streamer():
        while True:
            yield "<p>{}</p>".format(datetime.now())
            sleep(1)

return Response(streamer())
```

This does not work when we use an AWS ALB as the load balancer - the client is unable to read from the stream. Is this a limitation on the AWS ALB side? Should I consider using AWS NLB instead?

Comment: HTTP/2 and gRPC Support - It has features like efficient binary serialization and support for numerous languages in addition to the inherent benefits of HTTP/2 like lighter network footprint, compression, and bi-directional streaming making it better than the legacy protocols like REST.
https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/application-load-balancer/